# TSQL : conditional query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table :

```
| RoomID | OrderID | Occupancy | rn |
+--------+---------+-----------+----+
| 01     | 101     | Vacant    | 1  |
| 01     | 102     | Occupied  | 2  |
| 01     | 103     | Occupied  | 3  |
| 01     | 104     | Vacant    | 4  |
| 02     | 201     | Vacant    | 1  |
| 02     | 202     | Occupied  | 2  |
| 02     | 203     | Vacant    | 3  |
| 03     | 301     | Vacant    | 1  |
| 03     | 302     | Occupied  | 2  |
| 03     | 303     | Occupied  | 3  |
| 03     | 304     | Occupied  | 4  |
| 04     | 401     | Occupied  | 1  |
| 04     | 402     | Occupied  | 2  |
| 04     | 403     | Vacant    | 3  |
| 04     | 404     | Occupied  | 4  |
```

I need to flag the `RoomID`s where all of the following requirments are met as 'Yes' and if one or more requirements are not met as 'No':

- when `rn` = 1 the `Occupancy` is vacant
- When `rn` = 2 the `Occupancy` is Occupied
- Any `rn` larger than 2 (3,4,5..) has an `Occupancy` of vacant

The result should look like the following:

```
| RoomID | OrderID |
+--------+---------+
| 01     | Yes     |
| 02     | Yes     |
| 03     | No      |
| 04     | No      |
```

I have an impression that this is easy but I cannot see it at the moment, thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: can you post your attempt to solve it?

Comment: Do you want the 'Yes' or 'No' for each RoomID or each combination of 'RoomID' and 'OrderID'?

Comment: @DVT RoomID only.

Comment: the roomID 1 have rn = 3 and occupancy = occupied so don't should be YES like in your sample

Comment: @scaisEdge rn = 1 has to be vacant , rn = 2 has to be occupied  after that any rn > 2 can be vacant ( as long as there is one that is vacant)

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Comment: The solutions below all assume that `rn` values > 2 must be `'Vacant'`, but the question and @H.Ben's follow-up comment say that "at least one `rn` value > 2 must be `'Vacant'`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builds on 'Yes' > 'No'

```
 select RoomId, 
        min(case when rn<>2 and Occupancy='vacant' 
                 or rn=2 and Occupancy='Occupied' 
            then 'Yes' else 'No' end) res
 from  myTable
 group by RoomId
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a CASE to calculate the rule for each row.
When the minimum of that rule (grouped by room_id) is 0, then at least 1 of them didn't follow the rule.

```sql
SELECT RoomID,
IIF(MIN(
    CASE 
    WHEN rn <> 2 AND Occupancy = 'Vacant' THEN 1
    WHEN rn = 2 AND Occupancy = 'Occupied' THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
    END)=0,'No','Yes') as OccupancyRule
FROM RoomOccupancyTable
GROUP BY RoomID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Aggregation to check each condition.

```
with roomquery as (
     select RoomId, 
            min(case when rn<>2 and Occupancy='vacant' then 1 else 0 end) cond1,
            min(case when rn=2 and Occupancy='Occupied' then 1 else 0 end) cond2
     from rooms r
     group by RoomId)
select RoomId, 
       case when Cond1=1 and Cond2=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end Status
from roomquery
```

Note: you can rewrite it and use only one condition or eve remove the CTE (with statement) altogether, but I believe this is more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you.

```
SELECT RoomID,
CASE WHEN ((rn = 1 OR rn > 2) AND Occupancy = 'Vacant') AND (rn = 2 AND Occupancy = 'Occupied') THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer that counts the number of violations per RoomID in a subquery and then prints "yes" or "no" accordingly:

```
SELECT sub.roomid,
CASE WHEN sum(sub.orderid_no) IS NOT NULL THEN 'No'
ELSE 'Yes'
END AS orderID
FROM
(SELECT roomid, 
CASE WHEN rn = 1 AND occupancy = 'occupied' THEN 1
WHEN rn = 2 AND occupancy = 'vacant' THEN 1
WHEN rn > 2 AND occupancy = 'occupied' THEN 1
END AS orderid_no
FROM T) sub
GROUP BY sub.roomid
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9d467/14

Also, I think your output above is mistaken. According to your data, RoomID 01 should have OrderID "No"